# How to implement isomorphism for React app with .Net Core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, isomorphic-javascript

I have created a new starter project based on the "reactredux" template provided by .Net Core (2.1) and I see that it doesn't implement isomorphism.

There's some hints that it should be supported though as the following line is present in index.js:

```
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
```

Also [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#server-side-prerendering), ASP.Net core provides a number of tag helpers for pre-rendering JavaScript on the server. However, the documentation only provide examples for Angular.

So I'm not quite sure how to actually modify the starter "reactredux" project to use this. I guess that I need to install the `aspnet-prerendering` package, then change my index.htm to an ASP.Net core index.cshtml, but then I'm not quite sure what to put in the `asp-prerender-module` tag. I don't have an entry point for `main-server` and I don't see any documentation on how to add one.

Has anyone gone through this before and would be able to provide some steps or guidance?

Comment: Have you look at the github page of SpaServices? They have one example of pre-rendering for React-Webpack: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#5b-prerendering-react-components

Comment: Oh dear, the documentation provides a nice 404 link to the example of "boot-server.tsx" I'm looking for... 
I also tried to follow their instructions: "_To get a working starting point for an ASP.NET Core site with React+Redux on the client (and server-side prerendering), see the [aspnetcore-spa generator](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/)._", and ended up with the following warning in the console at the last step: "_Please use "dotnet new" templates instead [...] This Yeoman generator is DEPRECATED_" => back to square 1...

Comment: I found the old sources for the sample react + redux project that used to implement pre-rendering: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/64ed1c794521999193271d7c4ae3e39c97fac6db/templates/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/redux/ClientApp . Need to digest that now...

Comment: Aside from using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` as in your link, `prerender-spa-plugin` might be an alternative choice. You can take a look.